# daemonizing a lua script

Tags: linux, lua, posix

I want to daemonize a lua script;
Fortunately, I see that the luaposix package offers a `unistd` interface, so I can call fork() etc. Unfortunately, it DOES NOT offer the setsid() function, so though I've been able to write a simple daemon, it's not complete.

I also saw that there's a luarocks package named luadaemon available spefically for this. Unfortunately, it fails to compile correctly and seems to not really be supported or developed.

I'm thinking of writing my own 'luadaemon' in C if I can't find an alternative, but I wanted to double-check first.

Is there any way to daemonize a lua script?

PS:

- I'm not interested in systemd etc options
- I already know about start-stop-daemon

What I'm interested in is if there's any way to write a daemon in lua directly only using lua modules.

Comment: Is LuaJIT an option for you? ffi.C makes it very easy to call C functions. Alternatively look at this lib which features the function you need: https://neopallium.github.io/nixio/modules/nixio.html

Comment: Thanks. The nixio library might be just what I need

Comment: @sneusse is there anyway do daemonize the script by calling a C function? I've tried writing a C module that presents a daemonize() function the script can call. Unfortuantely the script itself, as expected, doesn't get daemonized even though the call to fork etc succeeds